# Python, SQLAlchemy and MySQL, odd characters

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a MySQL database defined with collation UTF8. A table 'clientes' and all its columns are specified as UTF8.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `clientes`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientes` (
  `ID` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `clientes` (`ID`, `nombre`) VALUES
('111', 'María Español Marqués'),
('222', 'Paulo Conceiçao'));
```

Queries with MySQL clients (in terminal, phpmyadmin...) displays characters fine:

```
mysql> select * from clientes;
+-----+--------------------------+
| ID  | nombre                   |
+-----+--------------------------+
| 111 | María Español Marqués    |
| 222 | Paulo Conceiçao          |
+-----+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I create the class with SQLAlchemy:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

engine = create_engine('mysql://root:toor@localhost')
engine.execute("USE nTal")
Base = declarative_base()

class Cliente(Base):

    __tablename__ = "clientes"

    ID = Column(String(35), primary_key=True)
    nombre = Column(String(255))

    def __init__(self, nombre):
        """"""
        self.nombre = nombre

engine.dispose()
```

When I run a query with SQLAlchemy, I get odd characters with accents, spanish and portuguese simbols are not visible.

```
res = session.query(Cliente).all()
for cliente in res:
    print cliente.ID + ", " + cliente.nombre

111, Mar�a Espa�ol Marqu�s
222, Paulo Concei�ao
```

Of course, I have search a lot about enconding and decoding, but the most I find is about errors, not about incorrect displaying.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your font even contain spanish haracters?

Comment: Yes, of course: I'm spanish...

Comment: Tell more about your OS. How is locale configured?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10, locale: LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=es_ES LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8", and so on... The odd characters are obtained in PyCharm IDE and also in terminal.

Comment: Can you figure out character codes of these characters? Are they all replaced by � or this is only a replacement character showed instead of character missing in font?

Comment: @Tupteq, this could be a clue; if I explode in letters the string:  
print letter, ord(letter), I get that the first letter (must be an accented i) is 237. I'ts a normal letter in spanish, and I have no problems at all whith the fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding "?charset=utf8" to the connection string:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:******@localhost?charset=utf8')
```

Comment: Nice. If you would use mysql+mysqlconnector (and Install MySQL Connector/Pyton), I think it should work without the extra option.